# InstallShield LE won't swap .EXE for newer version

Tags: .net, installshield

I set up the Upgrade Paths just like described in the other answers on this site. The entry in the add/remove programs changes to the latest version, the older version gets removed, but when I run the program it is not updated. The .EXE file is the older one, and the new one doesn't exist. I change the product code and keep the upgrade code the same. I create a new Upgrade path and point it in the direction of the older .MSI.

What is wrong?

Comment: Off topic? Not!  What is the Win32 file version / .NET AssemblyFileVersion of the old and new file?

Comment: Damn! they are the same. Thanx for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the MSDN Help Topic [File Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are a number of pages off of that one including [Both Files Have a Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

InstallShield LE uses Windows Installer.

Answer (score 0):

As Christopher answered above, just a bit more addition. I had the same problem and Installshield LE doesn't have the option to always overwrite exe (chooses "Windows Installer versioning rules (recommended)" as default) so you have to increment the exe file's version manually.

In YourSetupApplication -> Specify Application data -> Files tree,
-Right click your exe file and select properties
-Check the box that says Override system version and give the new updated version in the box.

Now you can rebuild the setup and install, it will overwrite the exe!

Cheers!